# Reduced VS non-reduced cohomology ring

Tags: algebraic-topology

Assume cohomology ring of topological space $X$ has the form:

$H^{*}(X) = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^k)$, where $x \in H^{1}(X)$ is a generator.

What can I say of its reduced cohomology ring $\tilde{H}^{*}(X)$? Will it just be free (non-unital) ring on generator $x$ modulo $x^k$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: How many spaces do you actually know with this cohomology ring?

Comment: As for your question - interpreted in a wider context - the reduced cohomolgy $\tilde H^*(X)$ is the kernel of the ring homomorphism $H^*X\rightarrow H^*\ast$. So everything you know about kernels of ring homomorphisms is true here.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find proof of this?

Comment: Proof? It's the definition, see for example here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+(Eilenberg-Steenrod)+cohomology#RelationBetweenReducedAndUnreduced